# Filter list of files from directory in python

Tags: python

I have the below files in a directory.

Directory: /home/user_name/files/

```
pytest.py
jobrun.log
First_new_2021-09-17.log
Last_new_2021-09-17.log
First_new_2021-09-16.log
Last_new_2021-09-16.log
```

My expected output is to list only those files which have *new* and the date should be matching the current date.

Expected output:

```
First_new_2021-09-17.log
Last_new_2021-09-17.log
```

How to achieve this in python.

Comment: Can you please share your progress? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Look up `glob()`.

Comment: What are you struggling with? Getting list of files in a directory? Filtering out files with new in them? Filtering out files with today's date in them? Starting python?

Comment: I am not able to filter it.  I am using os.listdir(directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use os

```
import datetime
import os
        
thedate  = datetime.datetime.now()    
filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(mydir) if thedate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  in f ]
```

Comment: it will match the file with a name `Last_2021-09-17.log`  and `Last_2021-09-17.pdf` which is not a valid result

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using python's in-build library glob.
Docs: *https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html*\

```py
import time
from glob import glob

###Since you are working in the same directory, you can simply call glob to find all the files with the extention '.log' by using the wildcard expression '*'.
###Now to get current date you can use time module

today_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
file_loc = glob(f'*{today_date}.log')
print(file_loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) implementation:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date


folder = Path("/home/user_name/files/")
today = date.today()
match = today.strftime("*new_%Y-%m-%d.log")

matching = [fp for fp in folder.glob(match)]
print(matching)
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably your solution should look like:

```
import datetime
import re
import os

today = datetime.date.today() # date today
f_date = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # format the string

pattern = re.compile(fr"[\w]+_new_{f_date}.log") # create a pattern to match your files with

result = []

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/user_name/files/'): # iterate over the directories
   for file in files: # iterate over each file in the current directory
       res = pattern.match(file) # find match
       if res := res.group(0): # get name matching the result
          result.append(res) # append name to a list of results

print(result)
```